# If you delete an account are you allowed to recreate?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

So I accidentally signed up for a Stack Exchange site and if I delete an account there, am I allowed to create it back again? This is just in case I need it.

Comment: I don't immediately see a problem with that if you're not attempting to circumvent bans and stuff like that. But why delete it if you want to recreate it anyway?

Comment: @Bart, Well say I delete it and thinking I dont' need it. But then 6 months later, I return and think OMG I need that

Comment: Why bother deleting it? I have loads of 101-rep accounts on loads of SE sites which I've since forgotten about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...yes. Unless you were a bad person and got yourself banned, you can re-create an account. You do have to ask a moderator to delete the old account, though.

Comment: If the account has never voted or posted more than once, they can insta-delete it themselves.

Comment: @animuson You have to request it if it voted or posted right? Just curious

Comment: I can confirm that this works.  Early in one site's history I created an account to post a comment, later decided I didn't want it and deleted it (I think I asked the team because I didn't know what I was doing back then), and much later created a new account on that site with the same OpenID.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That sounds different than what the question asks; was the second account new or an undeletion?

Comment: It was a new account (different user number).  I thought the question was about getting back on the site as opposed to getting that specific account back, sorry.  Deleted accounts pretty much can't be undeleted; in extraordinary circumstances they can rebuild them (re-associate posts, that sort of thing), but not for normal "oops, shouldn't've deleted that" cases.